# UITest failing on Device farm

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest, aws-device-farm

I created an ipa file of my application from product-> Archive-> Distribute-> Appstore-> Export. I used this ipa for UITest on the device farm. First I tried with Standard environment which gave me the below error -

**Setup Test skipped: Not enough suites found to execute**

Then I tried with custom environment with Default TestSpec for iOS XCTest UI and I got issue on launching the application. I got the below error from device farm -

> UITests.swift:20: error: -[SomeAppUITests.SomeAppUITests testExample]
> : Failed to get launch progress for <XCUIApplicationImpl: 0x280b47bd0
> com.developer.SomeApp.Staging at
> /private/tmp/scratchPTi3vk.scratch/Productsedbz37/Debug-iphoneos/SomeApp.app>:
> Unable to launch com.developer.SomeApp.Staging. (Underlying Error:
> Request to launch com.developer.SomeApp.Staging failed. The operation
> couldn’t be completed. The process failed to launch. : Failed to
> launch process with bundle identifier 'com.developer.SomeApp.Staging'.
> (Underlying Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The process
> failed to launch. (Underlying Error: The operation couldn’t be
> completed. Launch failed. (Underlying Error: Launchd job spawn failed
> with error: 88. Malformed Mach-o file))))

Then I tried the fuzz test, but it gave me a different error. Here's the screenshot -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN5hQ.jpg

Comment: did you try to launch locally ?

Comment: Does this app work on a local phone? Also, what are the xcodebuild args that your app is using to build?

Comment: Hello, ever succeeded to run Standard environment?